# Convert a nx1 matrix to square diagonal matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix 10x1 matrix a as follows:

```
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]  133
 [3,]  206
 [4,]  104
 [5,]  159
 [6,]    0
 [7,]   89
 [8,]  134
 [9,]    0
[10,]  119
```

I am trying to convert this to a 10x10 diagonal matrix as follows:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    133  0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    206  0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    104  0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    159  0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    89   0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    134  0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     119
```

I have tried some basic approaches like `diag(a, 10, 10)` nothing worked, running out of ideas, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `diag(as.vector(a))`

Comment: @bdecaf, absolutely correct. Please post this in the answer section so I can give you some points.

Comment: A slightly shorter version would be `diag(c(a))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit short answer:

`diag(as.vector(a))`